# class not found: "com.example.libinsta.apis.instaapiv3tests"

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When running `get_tags_working` function it shows:

> class not found: "com.example.libinsta.apis.instaapiv3tests"

```
package com.example.libinsta.apis

import junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import org.junit.Test
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory

class InstaAPIv3Tests {

    private  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor{
            val request = it.request().newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization","Client-ID 6812c9195197fb9")
                .build()
            it.proceed(request)
        }
        .build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("https://api.imgur.com/3/").build()
    private val api = retrofit.create(InstaAPIv3::class.java)

    @Test
    fun `get_tags_working`(){
        val response = api.getTags().execute()
        assertNotNull(response.body())
    }

    @Test
    fun `get_galleries_working`(){
        val response = api.getGallery().execute()
        assertNotNull(response.body())
    }
}
```

I have this file in my app folder but it still showing this error